# Can i integrate hive with flutterflow or give me a suggestion where i can store my pdf files and can access it in my flutterflow project?

Tags: flutter, hive, flutterflow

I have tried it, but there is no tutorials of hive with flutterflow.

I have also tried it with firebase, but there is difficulties in fetching the data from firebase storage.

Now i want some other option to store data locally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.